# Trying to make the click eventlistener work but it's not working. Does anyone know what would be the issue?

Tags: javascript, click, addeventlistener

so I just started to learn JS and just don't understand why my code isn't working. What I'm trying to do? There are three buttons that disappear when you click on them, so I want to make them show up again once someone resets the app (once someone closes the window) so you can try from the beginning. Probably that doesn't make sense what I just said so the point is I'm trying to use the click eventlistener to show buttons again when someone clicks the button. What did I do wrong here?

```
 let optionClick = document.querySelectorAll('.option');
    for (let i = 0; i < optionClick.length; i++) {
      optionClick[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        this.style.display = "none";

      });
    }

    let showOptions = document.querySelector(".button");
    showOptions.addEventListener("click", function () {
      optionClick.style.display = "block";
    });
```

```
  <div class="app">
    <div class="white">
      <img class="marker" src="marker.png" />
      <img class="wheel" src="wheel.png" />
      <img onclick="myFunction()" class="button" src="button.png" />


    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="congratulation hidden">
    <button onclick="closeWindow()" class="close-window">X</button>
    <h2>Congratulation!</h2>
    <h4>Choose your prize:</h4>
    <button class="option">
      <p>x</p>
    </button>
    <button class="option">
      <p>x</p>
    </button>
    <button class="option">
      <p>x</p>
    </button>
```

I want to make buttons showing up again when someone clicks the button

Comment: Which button is meant to reset the other buttons?

Comment: ".button", I want this .button to make other buttons show up again

Comment: the element with the class `.button` appears to be an image element. This is a bit unintuitive for other people to read and understand.

Comment: OK, that's a little confusing. You want the buttons to reset when the image with `.button` is clicked, but in your question you say _"once someone resets the app (once someone closes the window)"_. Those are contradictory requirements. @Veronica

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to iterate over your `optionClick` when you add an eventListener to `showOptions`.

```js
let showOptions = document.querySelector(".button");
showOptions.addEventListener("click", function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < optionClick.length; i++) {
    optionClick[i].style.display = "block";
  }
});
```